# Rinkeby.io faucet keeps returning Invalid User...Boom. I need testnet ether. Please

Tags: rinkeby

My Address is 0x6dcade1808756840da3d5ce49182d80517895f67

I have tried over and over with rinkeby.io faucet through gist.github.  The faucet keeps on saying "invalid user, boom".

I would like to test out contracts on testnet.  Can someone send me a few.  Greatly appreciated.  Thank you

[image]

Comment: Not sure why is was marked as duplicate. I'm experiencing same issue and the posted answer does not answer the question.